# Hadoop - 3 Data nodes are alive up and running but the report/url is not showing the live data nodes

Tags: hadoop, centos, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have One Name Node (Master Node)and 3 Data Node(Slave Nodes) .I have configured a single data node in Name node itself which is working fine and Showing up in the report. All the daemon are up an running individually but the 3 Data Nodes(Slave Nodes) are not listed in the hadoop dfsadmin -report.

When the jps is initiated everything looks good. :

**Name Node**

```
[hadoop@master ~]$ jps
4338 Jps
2114 NameNode
2420 SecondaryNameNode
2696 NodeManager
2584 ResourceManager
2220 DataNode
```

**Slave Node**
[hadoop@slave1 ~]$ jps
2114 NodeManager
2229 Jps
2015 DataNode

**Slave Node**

```
[hadoop@slave2 ~]$ jps
2114 NodeManager
2229 Jps
2015 DataNode
```

**Slave Node**
[hadoop@slave3 ~]$ jps

```
2114 NodeManager
2229 Jps
2015 DataNode 

[hadoop@master ~]$ **hadoop dfsadmin -report**
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

16/07/14 21:27:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Configured Capacity: 7092494336 (6.61 GB)
Present Capacity: 1852854272 (1.73 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1852821504 (1.73 GB)
DFS Used: 32768 (32 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
```

---

```
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 192.168.1.160:50010 (nn1)*(### comment - this is data node configured in the name node itself)*
Hostname: nn1
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 7092494336 (6.61 GB)
DFS Used: 32768 (32 KB)
Non DFS Used: 5239640064 (4.88 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1852821504 (1.73 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 26.12%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Thu Jul 14 21:27:46 IST 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue resolved - The problem is just because the Data Node/Slave Nodes are not able to communicate with the Master Node. This is because the Firewall system in the master node is not accepting the incoming connection from the data node. There are two way to react to the situation

1. You have to allow incoming communication by the (IP) of salve nodes in Master node
2. Disable Firewall.

I have worked with the 2nd  option:
Type in the following below command in the master node to disable the firewall.

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```